# How can I enable calling over Wifi for a T-Mobile based Moto X?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-droid-x, t-mobile

T-Mobile allows for unlimited calling [when I'm tethered over Wifi](http://www.t-mobile.com/company/PressReleases_Article.aspx?assetName=Prs_Prs_20070627&title=T-Mobile%20Introduces%20Unlimited%20Calling%20Over%20Wi-Fi%20With%20the%20National%20Launch%20of%20T-Mobile%20HotSpot%20@Home), on my old Blackberry Bold this was called "UMT" or something like that  (it would appear in the status bar).

Since I still have poor reception I rely on wifi calling to get signal in the basement of my house.

How can I enable this T-Mobile specific (and no it's not Skype) wifi calling to work over a standard Wifi connection?

Answer (score 1):

The Moto X [does not support T-Mobile's WiFi calling](http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-8370). Customer support reps have stated that this is because [it is not a carrier branded device](https://support.t-mobile.com/message/294537#294537), meaning they have not modified the system ROM to add this feature:

> The Moto X does work on our network but because it is not a T-Mobile branded device we do not support WiFi Calling on it.

You'll either need to set up some other VoIP service or get a different phone that supports this.